# Display recapacha after 3 invalid login attempts?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, recaptcha

```
Private Sub CheckLogin()

If Failed == 3
    'show recapacha
    If Page.IsValid Then
    CheckLogin2()
    End If
End If
Else
Try
    'login code
    ' on password fail Failed+1
End Try
End If
```

What I have is a login form but I do not want to show the recapacha till there are 3 invalid login attempts. I'm not sure as to the best way to do that. Above is some mockup code to get an idea on where I am heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CheckLogin()

    'after the three attempts 
    If (LoginCount = 3) Then
        'show captcha code
        Return
    End If
    'your login code if found unsuccessful increase the counter
    LoginCount += 1

End Sub
```

> Property to increase the counter and check the number of login
>   attempts

```
Public Property LoginCount() As Integer
    Get
        If (ViewState("LoginCount") = Nothing) Then
            ViewState("LoginCount") = 0
        End If
        Return DirectCast(ViewState("LoginCount"), Integer)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        ViewState("LoginCount") = value
    End Set
End Property
```